# Convert values-as-list of a dictionary to values-as-tuple (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a dictionary:
`{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b':['a', 'c', 'e'], 'c':['a', 'b', 'f']}`

How can I get the values as tuple in one line:
`{'a': ('b', 'c'), 'b':('a', 'c', 'e'), 'c':('a', 'b', 'f')}`

---

First I converted the values of this dictionary to list of tuple using comprehension

`list_of_tuple = [tuple(val) for val in dict.values()]`

Iterating over the *values of dict* and *items in list_of_tuple*, then equating nth element of dict to nth element of list_of_tuple doesn't work.

Is there a better, compact way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
out = {k:tuple(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

or `map` with lambda:

```
out = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0],tuple(x[1])), d.items()))
```

or `map` with `zip`:

```
out = dict(zip(d.keys(), map(tuple, d.values())))
```

Output:

```
{'a': ('b', 'c'), 'b':('a', 'c', 'e'), 'c':('a', 'b', 'f')}
```